# Why "every?" has '?' where as "some" doesnt have '?' in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is fundamental difference for having a '?' in `every?` and not in `some` functions of clojure?

```
user> (every? true? [true true false])
false

user> (some true? [true false false])
true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`every?` returns true or false, so it gets a question mark. `some` doesn't return a boolean, it returns "the first logically true value returned by pred", and returns `nil` otherwise.

Here's the lame example I came up with:

```
user=> (some #(if (= 0 %) 1 0)  [1 3 5 0 9])
0
```

The first element in the collection gets passed into the predicate, the predicate evaluates to 0, which is logically true so `some` returns 0. you can see `some` is not returning true or false.

So `every?` gets a question mark because it returns true or false.
`some` returns the value returned by `pred` or nil, so it doesn't get a question mark.

Comment: Thanks. I tried one more and makes it clear. `(some #{2 3 4 5 } [2 3 4 5 6 ])` gives o/p `2`. I expected the `some` to return booleans. Arrgh. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @nestle: that is a better example

Comment: Additionally, if you do want to return a boolean using some, you can wrap it in the boolean function: (boolean (some #{2 3 4 5 } [2 3 4 5 6 ])) => true

Answer (score 0):

some doesn't necessarily return a Boolean, whereas every? always does.  See the [documentation.](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some)

> Returns the first logical true value of (pred x) for any x in coll,
>   else nil.  One common idiom is to use a set as pred, for example
>   this will return :fred if :fred is in the sequence, otherwise nil:
>   (some #{:fred} coll)